# Sorting sets alphabetically, letters in sets separated by commas

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-8, comparator

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{

    HashSet set = new HashSet<String>();

    set.add("{}");
    set.add("{a}");
    set.add("{b}");
    set.add("{a, b}");
    set.add("{a, c}");

    sortedSet(set);
}

public static void sortedSet(HashSet set)
{
    List<String> setList = new ArrayList<String>(set);
    List<String> orderedByAlpha = new ArrayList<String>(set);

    //sort by alphabetical order
    orderedByAlpha = (List<String>) setList.stream()
        .sorted((s1, s2) -> s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(orderedByAlpha);
}
```

I am trying to sort alphabetically but the output I get is this :

```
[{a, b}, {a, c}, {a}, {b}, {}]
```

but it should be:

```
[{a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b}, {}]
```

Comment: Alphabetically, `,` (0x2C) comes before `}` (0x7D).  If you expect a different result, you will need to write your own custom comparator.

Answer (score 0):

You're output doesn't match your code. You are showing 2D array lists, but your converting to a 1D arraylist, doesn't make sense.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    test(Arrays.asList("a", "d", "f", "a", "b"));
}

static void test(List<String> setList)
{
    List<String> out = setList.stream().sorted((a, b) -> a.compareToIgnoreCase(b)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(out);
}
```

This is properly sorting 1D arrays, so you're correct there.

You'll probably need to implement your own comparator to compare the 2D array lists to sort them.

Answer (score 0):

instead of having the source as a `List<String>` I'd recommend you have it as a `List<Set<String>>` e.g.

```
List<Set<String>> setList = new ArrayList<>();
setList.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a","b")));
setList.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a","c")));
setList.add(new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList("a")));
setList.add(new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList("b")));
setList.add(new HashSet<>());
```

Then apply the following comparator along with the mapping operation to yield the expected result:

```
List<String> result = 
     setList.stream()
         .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Function<Set<String>, Boolean>) Set::isEmpty)
                        .thenComparing(s -> String.join("", s),
                        String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))
         .map(Object::toString)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and this prints:

```
[[a], [a, b], [a, c], [b], []]
```

note that, currently the result is a list of strings where each string is the string representation of a given set. if however, you want the result to be a `List<Set<String>>` then simply remove the `map` operation above.

**Edit:**

Managed to get a solution working based on your initial idea....

So, first, you need a completely new comparator instead of just `(s1, s2) -> s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2)` as it will not suffice.

Given the input:

```
Set<String> set =  new HashSet<>();

set.add("{}");
set.add("{a}");
set.add("{b}");
set.add("{a, b}");
set.add("{a, c}");
```

and the following stream pipeline:

```
List<String> result = set.stream()
            .map(s -> s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", ""))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::isEmpty)
                    .thenComparing(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))
            .map(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(""))
                            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then we would have a result of:

```
[{a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b}, {}]
```

Comment: Your solution for sorting the strings does not handle elements with more than one character correctly. But since the OP’s problem is caused only by the curly braces, why not use `.map(s -> s.substring(1, s.length()-1)) .sorted(…) .map(s -> '{'+s+'}')`? Or, do the change only for the comparison, `set.stream() .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.substring(1, s.length()-1), Comparator.comparing(String::isEmpty) .thenComparing(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Holger good shout, guess I was over complicating things. I’ll leave it for the OP to take into consideration both of your valid points rather than updating the answer again. :)

Comment: @Holger Both of your solutions create new strings. Why not looping simply over the strings? The code would be a bit longer by much faster.

Comment: @ETO because the OP didn’t ask for the fastest solution. If it were for my project, I didn’t use a string representation for what seems to be a collection, so the problem did not arise in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as @Aomine and @Holger noted already, you need a custom comparator.

But IMHO their solutions look over-engineered. You don't need any of costly operations like `split` and `substring`:

- `String.substring` creates a new `String` object and calls `System.arraycopy()` under the hood
- `String.split` is even more costly. It iterates over your string and calls `String.substring` multiple times. Moreover it creates an `ArrayList` to store all the substrings. If the number of substrings is big enough then your `ArrayList` will need to expand its capacity (perhaps not only once) causing another call of `System.arraycopy()`.

For your simple case I would slightly modify the code of built-in `String.compareTo` method:

```
Comparator<String> customComparator =
            (s1, s2) -> {
                int len1 = s1.length();
                int len2 = s2.length();

                if (len1 == 2) return 1;
                if (len2 == 2) return -1;

                int lim = Math.min(len1, len2) - 1;

                for (int k = 1; k < lim; k++) {
                    char c1 = s1.charAt(k);
                    char c2 = s2.charAt(k);
                    if (c1 != c2) {
                        return c1 - c2;
                    }
                }
                return len1 - len2;
            };
```

It will compare the strings with complexity `O(n)`, where `n` is the length of shorter string. At the same time it will neither create any new objects nor perform any array replication.

The same comparator can be implemented using `Stream API`:

```
Comparator<String> customComparatorUsingStreams =
            (s1, s2) -> {
                if (s1.length() == 2) return 1;
                if (s2.length() == 2) return -1;
                return IntStream.range(1, Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length()) - 1)
                        .map(i -> s1.charAt(i) - s2.charAt(i))
                        .filter(i -> i != 0)
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElse(0);
            };
```

You can use your custom comparator like this:

```
List<String> orderedByAlpha = setList.stream()
                                     .sorted(customComparatorUsingStreams)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(orderedByAlpha);
```

Comment: You ignored the fact that the OP used `compareToIgnoreCase`. I don’t know whether she will ever come back to SO to tell us, whether this is important. By the way, if it’s just for avoiding the copying overhead of `substring` operations, you can use `Comparator.comparing(s -> CharBuffer.wrap(s, 1, s.length()-1))`. But it might be that the hotspot optimizer manages to generate even better code when it detects that the result of a `substring` operation is used purely locally.

Comment: @Holger Well, the case can be ignored by using `Character.toUpperCase` like `.map(i -> Character.toUpperCase(s1.charAt(i)) - Character.toUpperCase(s2.charAt(i)))`. As for using `CharBuffer.wrap`, it still does not avoid creation of other objects. (AFAIK, it creates an instance of `CharBuffer` under the hood).

Comment: The `CharBuffer` returned by `wrap` is a lightweight wrapper around the original `String`. It’s cheaper than the creation of the `IntStream` in your second variant, which creates the `IntStream`, a `RangeIntSpliterator`, a `TerminalOp`, and eventually an `OptionalInt`, plus some other internally used objects. In the end, only the character copying costs associated with `String` creation (which is O(n)) is an actually expensive operation. Sometimes, even that difference does not matter so that the simplest solution is preferable. For a performance critical scenario, your loop may truly pay off.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The second variant is not cheap. Though in this particular case I would also use collections instead of string representation (as you commented below).

Answer (score 0):

A take on it (slightly similar to [the answer by Aomine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53366442/1421925)) would be to strip the strings of the characters that makes [`String#compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-) fail, in this case (`'{'` and `'}'`). Also, the special case that an empty string (`"{}"`) is to be sorted after the rest needs to be taken care of.

The following code implements such a comparator:

```
static final Comparator<String> COMPARE_IGNORING_CURLY_BRACES_WITH_EMPTY_LAST = (s1, s2) -> {
  Function<String, String> strip = string -> string.replaceAll("[{}]", "");
  String strippedS1 = strip.apply(s1);
  String strippedS2 = strip.apply(s2);
  return strippedS1.isEmpty() || strippedS2.isEmpty() ?
      strippedS2.length() - strippedS1.length() :
      strippedS1.compareTo(strippedS2);
};
```

Of course, this is not the most efficient solution. If efficiency is truly important here, I would loop through the characters, like `String#compareTo()` does, as [suggested by ETO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53415103/1421925).